# Redirect from http to https not working for not www page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I need to redirect all my traffic to https.

I use redirect rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It works good for main domain, and almost for all links in mobile subdomain:

```
http://m.example.com/index.htm
http://www.m.example.com/index.htm
http://www.m.example.com/
```

But it doesnt work for:

```
http://m.example.com/
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: If it works for `http://m.example.com/index.htm` and does not work for `http://m.example.com/` then there are probably some other rewrite rules above these, which affect this rewrite.

Comment: Or you are looking at a cached result from previous attempts.